# How to Change Height of Rectangle on Keypress?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am trying to figure out how to change the height of a box when a user presses up on the remote.

Here's the component:

```
   <component name="PlutoScene" extends="Scene">

   <script type="text/brightscript" uri="pkg:/components/homescreen.brs" />

   <children>
    <LayoutGroup id="root">
     <Rectangle id="header" width="1280" height="300" color="0x000000"> 
  </Rectangle>
  <LayoutGroup id="body" layoutDirection="horiz">
    <Rectangle id="rect1" height="270" width="400" color="0xffffff" />
    <Rectangle id="rect2" height="270" width="2" color="0x000000" />
    <Rectangle id="rect3" height="270" width="878" color="0xffffff" />
  </LayoutGroup>
  <Rectangle id="footer" width="1280" height="150" color="0x000000">
  </Rectangle>
</LayoutGroup>
 </children>
</component>
```

Here is the function in the homescreen.brs file:

```
sub init()
 m.rect1 = m.top.findNode("rect1")
 m.rect = m.rect1.boundingRect()
end sub

function onKeyEvent(key as String, press as Boolean) as Boolean
 if press then
  if (key = "Up") then
  m.rect.height = m.rect.height * 2
  end if
 end if
end function
```

Answer (score 2):

It is simpler than that. Change your **onKeyEvent** to this:

```
function onKeyEvent(key as String, press as Boolean) as Boolean
 if press then
  if (key = "Up") then
  m.rect1.height = m.rect1.height * 2
  end if
 end if
end function
```